# Tweaking seaborn.boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, boxplot, seaborn

I would like to compare a set of distributions of scores (`score`), grouped by some categories (`centrality`) and colored by some other (`model`). I've tried the following with seaborn:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
seaborn.boxplot(x="centrality", y="score", hue="model", data=data, palette=seaborn.color_palette("husl", len(models) +1))
seaborn.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
plt.savefig("/home/i11/staudt/Eval/properties-replication-test.pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
```

There are some problems I have with this plot:

- There is a large amount of outliers and I don't like how they are drawn here. Can I remove them? Can I change the appearance to show less clutter? Can I color them at least so that their color matches the box color?
- The `model` value `original` is special because all other distributions should be compared to the distribution of `original`. This should be visually reflected in the plot. Can I make `original` the first box of every group? Can I offset or mark it differently somehow? Would it be possible to draw a horizontal line through the median of each `original` distribution and through the group of boxes?
- some of the values of `score` are very small, how to do proper scaling of the y-axis to show them?

[image]

EDIT:

Here is an example with a log-scaled y-axis - also not yet ideal. Why do the some boxes seem cut off at the low end?

[image]

Comment: The blue outliers are a matplotlib bug, and they can be avoided by updating your seaborn. But I certainly wouldn't just remove the outliers!

Comment: Have you tried [log-scaling](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/horizontal_boxplot.html) the y variable?

Comment: @mwaskom Yes, but that "compresses" the bars of larger values very much at the top of the plot. Is there a compromise, i.e. log-scaling for just a part of the axis?

Comment: And sometimes the groups are hard to distinguish, e.g. if the boxes do not touch. Is it possible to draw vertical lines separating the groups?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Outlier display**

You should be able to pass any arguments to `seaborn.boxplot` that you can pass to `plt.boxplot` (see [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)), so you could adjust the display of the outliers by setting `flierprops`. [Here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_demo.html) are some examples of what you can do with your outliers.

If you don't want to display them, you could do

```
seaborn.boxplot(x="centrality", y="score", hue="model", data=data,
                showfliers=False)
```

or you could make them light gray like so:

```
flierprops = dict(markerfacecolor='0.75', markersize=5,
              linestyle='none')
seaborn.boxplot(x="centrality", y="score", hue="model", data=data,
                flierprops=flierprops)
```

**Order of groups**

You can set the order of the groups manually with `hue_order`, e.g.

```
seaborn.boxplot(x="centrality", y="score", hue="model", data=data,
                hue_order=["original", "Havel..","etc"])
```

**Scaling of y-axis**

You could just get the minimum and maximum values of all y-values and set `y_lim` accordingly? Something like this:

```
y_values = data["scores"].values
seaborn.boxplot(x="centrality", y="score", hue="model", data=data,
                y_lim=(np.min(y_values),np.max(y_values)))
```

EDIT: This last point doesn't really make sense since the automatic `y_lim` range will already include all the values, but I'm leaving it just as an example of how to adjust these settings. As mentioned in the comments, log-scaling probably makes more sense.

Comment: `flierprops` is nice. I tried passing `sym='+'` to `seaborn.boxplot` and it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @ zyxue instead of writing sym = '+' , write marker = '+'

Comment: There is no "y_lim" parameter in seaborn.boxplot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970932/setting-ylim-on-seaborn-boxplot

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since this answer has activity, but I'll answer OP's question regarding the weird looking lower-bounds for any people that need help in the future.

Once you set your y-axis to logarithmic scale, it becomes impossible to represent y=0, since log(0) tends to -inf.

Therefore, when the values regarding the lower part of your boxplot are either zero or very close to it the box has that look of seeming to be 'cut in half'.

Needless to say that it's also impossible to represent negative y values in a logarithmic scale.