# Matplotlib: Remove Single Marker

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a cdf with matplotlib. However, cdfs begin in the origin, thus I prepended zeros to the x and y arrays. The problem is now that the origin now is marked as a data point. I'd like to remove that single marker in the point (0,0).

Code and picture below.

```
#Part of the myplot (my own) class
def cdf(self):
    markers = ["x","v","o","^","8","s","p","+","D","*"]
    for index,item in enumerate(np.asarray(self.data).transpose()):
        x = np.sort(item)
        y = np.arange(1,len(x)+1) / len(x)
        x = np.insert(x,0,0)
        y = np.insert(y,0,0)
        self.plot = plt.plot(x,
                y,
                marker=markers[index],
                label=self.legend[index])
    self.setLabels( xlabel=self.xlabel,
                    ylabel="cumulative density",
                    title=self.title)
    self.ax.set_ylim(ymax=1)
```

[image]

Comment: you want to remove just the marker, or the marker and the line joining it to the second marker?

Comment: try to remove `x = np.insert(x,0,0)` and `y = np.insert(y,0,0)`

Comment: or give a name to `p(x,y)` and `p.remove()`

Comment: I only want to remove the marker. If I remove the lines @Veltro mentions then I will also lose that line segment... and that line segment is precisely the reason why I added that point in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove a marker. What you may do is to plot all the markers first, then append the origin and then plot a line.

```
x = np.sort(item)
y = np.arange(1,len(x)+1) / len(x)
self.plot, = plt.plot(x, y, marker=markers[index], ls="", label=self.legend[index])
x = np.insert(x,0,0)
y = np.insert(y,0,0)
self.plot2, = plt.plot(x, y, marker="", color=self.plot.get_color())
```

Alternative: Use the `markevery` argument.

```
x = np.sort(item)
y = np.arange(1,len(x)+1) / len(x)
x = np.insert(x,0,0)
y = np.insert(y,0,0)
markevery = range(1, len(x))
self.plot, = plt.plot(x, y, marker=markers[index], markevery=markevery, 
                      ls="", label=self.legend[index])
```

Comment: Kind of hacky, but it works, thx! I will wait a while before accepting this, because this is more of a workaround than an answer to the original question. Are you sure it is not possible to remove a marker in a similar style as it is possible to edit stuff in boxplots... see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354215/matplotlib-boxplot-showing-number-of-occurrences-of-integer-outliers