# How to annotate the minimum of a box plot in Seaborn excluding the outliers?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I have a dataset which has some outliers and I would like annotate the bottom leg of the box plot in Python. Here is an example of what I face right now:

```py
data = {'theta': [1 for i in range(0,10)],
       'error': [10,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
box_plot = sns.boxplot(x="theta", y='error', data=df, ax = ax1, showfliers = False)
min_value = df.groupby(['theta'])['error'].min().values
for xtick in box_plot.get_xticks():
    idx = df[df['error']==min_value[xtick]].index.values
    text = 'The minimum value before outliers is here'
    box_plot.text(xtick,min_value[xtick]+2, text, 
            horizontalalignment='center',size='x-small',weight='semibold')
    box_plot.plot(xtick,min_value[xtick], marker='*', markersize=20 )
```

This does not produce what I want
[image]

Instead, I would like to get this

[image]

Which I can get manually for this example, but I'd  like a more systematic approach that I can generalize to other instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735603/extract-outliers-from-seaborn-boxplot), Seaborn boxplots use matplotlib to generate the whiskers and quartiles for the boxplot that is drawn, so you can perform these same calculations using `matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats`.

You can also modify the range of the yticks using `ax1.set_yticks`, in case you ever want to display the outlier value of 10.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from matplotlib.cbook import boxplot_stats

data = {'theta': [1 for i in range(0,10)],
       'error': [10,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
box_plot = sns.boxplot(x="theta", y='error', data=df, ax = ax1, showfliers = False)
min_value = df.groupby(['theta'])['error'].min().values

## get the lower whisker
## you can retreive other boxplot values as well
low_whisker = boxplot_stats(df.error)[0]['whislo']

for xtick in box_plot.get_xticks():
    ## idx = df[df['error']==min_value[xtick]].index.values
    text = 'The minimum value before outliers is here'
    box_plot.text(xtick,low_whisker-2, text, 
            horizontalalignment='center',size='x-small',weight='semibold')
    box_plot.plot(xtick,low_whisker, marker='*', markersize=20)

## set the range to include the entire range of the data
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(min(df.error),max(df.error)+5,5))

plt.show()
```

[image]