# How to get outlier values for a specific category with boxplot_stats

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I'm trying to extract the outliers using a boxplot.

```
# libraries & dataset
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# set a grey background (use sns.set_theme() if seaborn version 0.11.0 or above) 
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

sns.boxplot(y=df["species"], x=df["sepal_length"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The above plot shows an outlier. I tried to extract the outliers using [boxplot_stats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736994/14045537). But the fliers show an empty array.

```
from matplotlib.cbook import boxplot_stats  
boxplot_stats(data["sepal_length"])
```

**Output**

```
[{'cihi': 5.966646952167348,
  'cilo': 5.633353047832651,
  'fliers': array([], dtype=float64),
  'iqr': 1.3000000000000007,
  'mean': 5.843333333333334,
  'med': 5.8,
  'q1': 5.1,
  'q3': 6.4,
  'whishi': 7.9,
  'whislo': 4.3}]
```

Is there a way to extract the outlier shown in the boxplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `'species'` needs to be specified.

  - `boxplot_stats(data["sepal_length"])` is the statistics for all `'species'`.
  - Use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to select the correct category.
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64191264/7758804) shows how to make the calculation using pandas methods.
- The **Notes** section of [`matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) shows how outliers are calculated.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
from matplotlib import boxplot_stats
import seaborn as sns

# load the data
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

boxplot_stats(df.loc[df.species.eq('virginica'), "sepal_length"])

[{'mean': 6.587999999999998,
  'iqr': 0.6750000000000007,
  'cilo': 6.350128717727511,
  'cihi': 6.649871282272489,
  'whishi': 7.9,
  'whislo': 5.6,
  'fliers': array([4.9]),
  'q1': 6.225,
  'med': 6.5,
  'q3': 6.9}]
```

### Get all outliers

```py
for species, data in df.groupby('species'):
    data = data.iloc[:, :-1]  # drop off the species column
    print(f'Outliers for: {species}')
    stats = boxplot_stats(data)
    for col, stat in zip(data.columns, stats):
        print(f"{col}: {stat['fliers'].tolist()}")
    print('\n')

[out]:
Outliers for: setosa
sepal_length: []
sepal_width: [2.3, 4.4]
petal_length: [1.1, 1.0, 1.9, 1.9]
petal_width: [0.5, 0.6]


Outliers for: versicolor
sepal_length: []
sepal_width: []
petal_length: [3.0]
petal_width: []


Outliers for: virginica
sepal_length: [4.9]
sepal_width: [2.2, 3.8, 3.8]
petal_length: []
petal_width: []
```

### `seaborn.catplot`

```py
sns.catplot(kind='box', data=df.melt(id_vars='species'), x='value', y='variable', hue='species', aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Does Filtering the fliers returns all the outliers? Like `df[df["sepal_length"] == 4.9]`

Comment: What you wrote returns all rows where sepal_length equals 4.9. My answer returns the stats only for sepal_length for the specific species, which includes all fliers. I’m going to bed now and won’t respond until after 9am PST (UTC-7)

Comment: How to return rows of outliers? Please respond when u r available.

Comment: @Pluviophile this question [how to use pandas filter with IQR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34782063/7758804) shows how to filter the dataframe. In the example dataframe, there are 3 species, each of which have 4 metrics. The calculation needs to be done for each group, because they all have different metrics.

Comment: I should filter each group and apply IQR and filter the data right?

Comment: @Pluviophile As far as I can tell that is what needs to happen. If you have additional issues applying those methods to your dataframe, you should open a new question, and be sure to reference the other question.