# setting ylim on seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to set ylim parameters on a seaborn boxplot?

as an example:

```
y = np.random.randn(300)
sns.boxplot (y=y)
```

Displays

[boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8D5m.jpg)

but if I try

```
ax.set_ylim=(-5, 5)
```

It makes no difference. Is it possible to set ylim values for a boxplot different from the default ones for a given dataset plot?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use the axes-approach without having an axes-object.

Try (figure-based approach):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ylim([-5,5])
```

or probably better in your case:

```
ax = sns.boxplot (y=y)
ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])      # function! your code-sample is wrong here!
```

The [docs here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) show the return-value of sns.boxplot.

And [here is the general overview of matplotlib's objects](https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html).